# Progress from Upload via Post

Tags: android, http, upload, progress-bar

i want to send text, pics etc via POST to a Server. Usually i used ASynchHTTPClient a class, which i found in web ( https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client ).

Now I want to get the effort from the upload, to visualize it with a progressbar.

Anyone a idea or knows how to realise this with to named class?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

check this http://toolongdidntread.com/android/android-multipart-post-with-progress-bar/